# Incorrect output from while loop

Tags: c, while-loop

This function asks for an integer between loLimit and hiLimit and allows the user to safely enter it. It keeps asking until the user enters a number in the legal range. Then it returns the legal number.

```
The correct output should be:
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 19
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 128
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 48
Please enter an integer between 48 and 127: 47
Please enter an integer between 48 and 127: 65
```

However, my output behaves strangely, it seems as if the loLimit value changes back and forth. Also, numbers are only recorded after entered twice.

```
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 2
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 150
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 56
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 56
Please enter an integer between 56 and 127: 66
Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 66
Please enter an integer between 66 and 127: 77
```

Here's my code:

```
int enterNumber (int loLimit, int hiLimit){
    int min;
    int max;

    do {
    printf("Please enter an integer between %d and %d:\n", loLimit, hiLimit);
    scanf("%d", &min);
    }
    while (min<loLimit || min>hiLimit);
    return min;
}

int main(){
    enterNumber(32,127);
    int min=enterNumber(32,127);

    enterNumber(min,127);
    int max=enterNumber(enterNumber(32,127),127);


}
```

Comment: The [scanf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fscanf.html) function can *fail* so you should *always* test its result (number of successfully scanned items)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the enterNumber() function 5 times so 5 accepted values are taken :

```
  enterNumber(32,127);
  Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 56 
  1st accepted number

  int min=enterNumber(32,127);
  Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 56  // 2nd one
  2nd accepted number

  enterNumber(min,127);
  Please enter an integer between 56 and 127: 66
  3rd accepted answer.

  int max=enterNumber(enterNumber(32,127),127);    //called twice
  Please enter an integer between 32 and 127: 66
  Please enter an integer between 66 and 127: 77
  4th and 5 th accepted answer
```

You can correct your logic by deleting the first and third enternumber call as shown .

```
   int enterNumber (int loLimit, int hiLimit){
   int min;
   int max;

   do {
      printf("Please enter an integer between %d and %d:\n", loLimit, hiLimit);
      scanf("%d", &min);
      }
   while (min<loLimit || min>hiLimit);
   return min;
  }

  int main(){
 // enterNumber(32,127); comment out this
  int min=enterNumber(32,127);

  // enterNumber(min,127);
   int max=enterNumber(min,127);
   int no=enterNumber(min,max);
```

}

First it accepts a minimum value , then a maximum and finally enters a no between this range.

Comment: Oh yea thats right! I commented out both line. However, when I entered the first legal value, the low and high range still prompt the same value, it only changes the second time I entered a legal value. Any ideas?

Comment: Check it now @Katherine.It enters a no between min and max finally.

Comment: this doesn't quite compile, because the compiler will raise a warning about the unused variable 'max' in the function: enterNumber();